# How to see full precision of the number in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, precision

I want to see the full precision of the result `0.1+0.2`. It would only give me `0.30000000000000004`. I can't use `Number(0.1+0.2).toPrecision()` since it can't show more than 21 digits. In Firefox I could do it like this:

```
console.log('%.60f', 0.1 + 0.2)
```

And it'd give me:

```
0.300000000000000044408920985006261616945266723632812500000000
```

How can I achieve the same in Chrome?